# Qt implemantation of Wddx

Tags: c++, qt, wddx

Is there any implemantation of Qt for Wddx packets? I am trying to convert an xml file into wddx packet to transmit over internet. QDomDocument doesn't have any support for Wddx packet writing or parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no such implementation meaning you would have to write your own class to have this functionality.

By using the existing QDom* functions you should be able to write it fairly easy as you don't have to write everything from scratch.